# convert gulp.src stream to array?

Tags: gulp

Is it possible to get the list of files coming from a `gulp.src` stream as an array, e.g.:

```js
var files = convertToArray(gulp.src('**/*.js'));
```

**Update:**

I was trying to move away from the [gulp-karma](https://github.com/karma-runner/gulp-karma) plugin:

```
gulp.task('test', function () {
    return gulp.src(files)
        .pipe($.order(ordering))
        .pipe($.karma({
            karma.conf.js'
         });
});
```

So my idea was:

```
gulp.task('test', function (done) {
    var karmaFiles = convertToArray(gulp.src(files)
        .pipe($.order(ordering)));

    new Server({
        configFile: karma.conf.js',
        files: karmaFiles
    }, done).start();
});
```

But as pointed out, this won't work because of it being async. Here's my solution:

```
gulp.task('test', function (done) {
    gulp.src(files)
        .pipe($.order(ordering)))
        .pipe(gutil.buffer())
        .on('data', function(data) {
            var karmaFiles = data.map(function(f) { return f.path; });
            new Server({
                configFile: __dirname + '/karma.conf.js',
                files: karmaFiles
            }, done).start();
        });

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gulp streams are always asynchronous so your hypothetical `convertToArray` function (which takes a stream and returns an array) is impossible.

The only way to get all the files in a stream is through some kind of callback function. The `gulp-util` package, which bundles various helper functions, provides the nice [`gutil.buffer()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-util#buffercb) :

```
var gutil = require('gulp-util');

gulp.src('**/*.js').pipe(gutil.buffer(function(err, files) {
  console.log('Path of first file:');
  console.log(files[0].path);
  console.log('Contents of first file:');
  console.log(files[0].contents.toString());
}));
```

In the above `files` will be an array of [`vinyl`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vinyl) files. That means for each file you have access to both the [`contents`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vinyl#filecontents) and the [`path`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vinyl#filepath) of the file.

If you don't care about the file contents and only want the path of each file you shouldn't be using `gulp.src()` at all. You should be using [`glob`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob) instead (which is what gulp is using internally). It gives you a synchronous method that returns an array of matching file paths:

```
var glob = require('glob');

var files = glob.sync('**/*.js');
console.log(files);
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about `gulp-util`, seems that will suit my needs. My case was slightly more complicated, it was using the `gulp-order` plugin as well, so getting the list of files from the stream in `gulp.src(files).pipe($.order(ordering))`

Comment: I updated my question to illustrate my issue, and included my solution. Let me know if you think there's a better way :)

Comment: Since you don't actually need the file contents you might want to use the [`read:false`](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#optionsread) option with `gulp.src()`. Saves the time to read the file contents unnecessarily. Otherwise it looks good.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks for the tip, I forgot about it reading the contents, might actually be able to improve other areas of the file too.

Comment: gulp-util was deprecated in December 2017 and (as it was essentially a collection of other modules) it had been planned to be sunsetted as early as 2014.  Its npmjs.org states: **gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, following the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5**